# auth-constraint - role-name - user - ignored

Tags: web-services, jsf, glassfish, jax-ws, java-ee-7

I am trying to learn about authentication in JAX-WS, so I made a small Netbeans8.0.2/Glassfish4.1 web application with a JAX-WS webservice, and I am trying to make it not public, but available to authorized users only.

The web.xml file for this webservice contains:

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Fib Web Service</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/FibServiceWithAuth/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>*</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    </login-config>
```

However, when I make another simple web app that is using this service,
it works without any authentication required, see here:

http://kempelen.ii.fmph.uniba.sk:8080/FibApp/

I understand that I should connect to the service from the JSF managed bean that handles this JSF page like this:

```
package fibapp;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class FibBean 
{
    public FibBean() { }

    int n;
    String result;

    public int getN() { return n; }
    public void setN(int newN) { n = newN; }

    public String getResult() { return result; }
    public void setResult(String newResult) { result = newResult; }

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://kempelen.ii.fmph.uniba.sk:8080/FibServiceWithAuth/FibWithAuth?wsdl")
    private FibWithAuth_Service fibService;

    public void compute() 
    {
        FibWithAuth fib = fibService.getFibWithAuthPort();
    //    ((BindingProvider) fib).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "someuser");
    //    ((BindingProvider) fib).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "somepass");
        result = fib.fib(n).toString();
    }
}
```

but even when those user/pass lines are commented out, the bean still gets the result from the webservice.

What is missing, please?

Answer (score 1):

In looking at your [WSDL](http://kempelen.ii.fmph.uniba.sk:8080/FibServiceWithAuth/FibWithAuth?wsdl) (as specified in your managed bean's `@WebServiceRef`), the endpoint of the service is

```
<soap:address 
location="http://kempelen.ii.fmph.uniba.sk:8080/FibServiceWithAuth/FibWithAuth"/>
```

which means your web service resource is `/FibWithAuth`.

However, your web.xml `<security-constraint>` url is

```
<url-pattern>/FibServiceWithAuth/*</url-pattern>
```

I think you want to change this to

```
<url-pattern>/FibWithAuth/*</url-pattern>
```

If you truly want to add the security constraint to the entire `FibServiceWithAuth` web application, then your `<security-constraint>` url pattern would be `/*`.

Lastly, I think you'll also want to change

```
<http-method>*</http-method>
```

to

```
<http-method>POST</http-method>
```

so that your managed bean can access the WSDL via `GET` request (per your `@WebServiceRef` annotation) without authentication.

Comment: excellent, many thanks! Now with the lines commented-out I am getting "com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized".  But when the lines are added, then I get "com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 403: Forbidden" - does it mean my user/password is incorrect? I tried to add the user with command-line "asadmin create-file-user". When trying to add the same user again, it reports "Adding User 2ain131 to file realm file failed.  User 2ain131 already exists." Is something still missing?

Comment: Update your post and include the full stack trace.  What's not clear is if WSDL retrieval is getting the 403 or the actual service invocation.  Did you follow the last suggestion of only security HTTP POST?

Comment: Yes, I updated the * to POST and followed all your suggestions, that moved me forward, but now still stuck on this forbidden. You can see the stack trace when you open the link, enter number and click the button: http://kempelen.ii.fmph.uniba.sk:8080/FibApp/